# Where can I sell ebooks for bitcoin?

Tags: publishing

What services/websites have you tried that you found favorable when it comes to selling your digital wares for bitcoin?

Comment: In the past i would recomend bitbooks but they died. Im also lookign for a place to sell pdf files for bitcoin.